# Trouble with redirects with multiple directories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain with two versions and I need to redirect 1 of the versions

```
test.example.ca
test.example.ca/en
test.example.ca/fr
```

I need the first domain test.example.com to redirect to test.example.ca/en anytime someone hits it. but i don't want test.example.ca/fr to redirect to test.example.com/en/fr

this is what I've been trying with no success.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =test.example.ca
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=test.example.ca/fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So what _should_ happen to requests to `https://test.example.ca/fr` ? Or more likely to requests to `https://test.example.com/fr`?

Comment: And one question you should answer yourself: do you really thing that "test.example.ca/fr" is a hostname? No? Then why do you test for that?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question such that you simply to *not* want requests to `https://test.example.com/fr...` to get redirected. So you want an exception.

I'd say this roughly is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr
RewriteRule ^ https://test.example.ca/en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Chances are that your question was wrong in a few details, to me it reads as if you were not really precise with your host names. But above should be the correct answer to what you actually asked.

You should implement such rules in the http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can also use a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess"). That file should be located in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder defined for your http host. And you need to make sure that the interpretation of such files is enabled *at all* (see the documentation for the `AllowOverride` directive for that).

It is a good idea to start out using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection first. And to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That prevents nasty caching issues on the client side.